# Revisiting our off-topic policy

Tags: discussion, site-scope, close-reasons

I've been meaning to post this question for a while, but only now got around to it. Over the last year or two, it has been my observation that a) the rate of (good) new questions has decreased noticeably and b) questions have been closed much more quickly as off-topic. (The first is borne out by the site stats on https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28815/computational-science -- although the mods might have access to more detailed site analytics than I as a 10k+ user -- while the second is personal observation, including my own behavior.)

I suspect a link between the two. Assuming we wish to grow our community (which is not a foregone conclusion, and may be argued here), **do we wish to revisit our off-topic policy to make it more inclusive?**

---

My own personal opinion -- which I'll detail in an answer below to be voted on -- is that for a site of our size, we don't have much to gain by being exclusive (and much more to gain by gaining a reputation for being welcoming like https://tex.stackexchange.com, which I hold as a model community on the internet), and restricting our scope to have no overlap with other sites would not leave a viable community. I would therefore appeal to voters to spend some time considering whether the question is really *irredeemably* off topic before casting their vote. (And I do not exempt myself here -- I noticed that I have gotten much more trigger-happy over time; in fact, this observation is what prompted this post.)

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas do you have an opinion on this?

Comment: @nicoguaro I am not sure if Chris can receive the notification, because he in not "present" in the page, I didn't receive the first notification (I saw the question because periodically check meta)

Comment: @nicoguaro I think the moderator "superping" only works in chatrooms, not in comment threads? So you'd have to ping people from chat with a message containing a link to this post.

Comment: @ChristianClason, the question is: who should I superping?

Comment: @nicoguaro Looking at the history of the off-topic review queue, I don't see any names that haven't commented on this topic yet -- so I'd say there's no further need for a superping. The question is where to go from here... My personal resolution on this is that I'm not going to let the review queue indicator pressure me into casting a vote unless I'm 100% sure about a question.

Comment: Another thing we should think about is to more clearly write [On-Topic Section](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  Right now it's a bit confusing, including references to [initiatives that are kind of inactive](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338/can-scicomp-stackexchange-be-used-for-project-specific-questions), as I know.

Comment: @nicoguaro, I looked a couple of months through the list of people actively using the _Close Votes_ queue. I would say most of them (if not all) already expressed their opinion here. I would say, only another moderator _Paul_ did not explicitly express his views here, probably should be superpinged.

Comment: This proposal should be more detailed. *How* exactly do you wish to change the on-topic rules? Do you have examples of recent questions that have been closed but in your opinion should have been open? It's easy to say "let's be more inclusive", but I would like to see how you suggest how you implement this in practice.

Answer (score 14):

## **Yes, and we should specify our policies to be more inclusive.**

(In fact, I believe the original consensus was much more inclusive, but community overturn meant that this more nuanced consensus was likely reduced to the simple close reasons.)

So that this can be linked to as a reference answer should this become our consensus (after possibly some editing), here's my view (based on earlier discussions on Meta) of our site scope:

### Software questions

As long as the software is clearly targeting **scientific computing** (among possibly others), the question should be **assumed to be on-topic** unless one of the following applies:

- Questions on **installing** and **running** the software are **off-topic**.
- Questions that are clearly **answered in the documentation** are **off-topic** (with *clearly* being the operative word here; if it's that obvious to you, courtesy would call for giving a pointer in a comment when voting to close).
- Question on software that have their **own Stack Exchange-style Q&A** should be **asked there**. (The rationale for this distinction is that the Q&A format is in fact superior to the old-style forums or mailing lists, so here would in principle be better, but if they have their own, they should try there first. If the did and couldn't get an answer, I'd welcome the question here.) Again, it'd be polite to accompany a vote to close with a link; I've tried to collect some in [Text blocks for frequent comments](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/421/1804), but this list is due for some curating.

Of course, one should still make some effort to ask a *good* software question; I've given my thoughts in [this answer](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/370/1804).

### Math questions

These are much less contentious, but for the sake of completeness: I'd only consider **undergraduate linear algebra and calculus/analysis** questions as **off-topic** and to be asked on https://math.stackexchange.com.

All others are **on-topic** here as long as they are conceivably relevant to **scientific computing**; in particular questions about **numerical analysis** and **optimization**. I think our core audience right now is application-oriented people requiring help with medium to advanced mathematical questions, and these are (*very*) poorly served by either math.stackexchange.com or mathoverflow.com.

(I'm not sufficiently familiar with **computer science** to comment on the corresponding situation, but I assume it is similar; I'd be interested in hearing the view of CS experts on this.)

### Programming questions

Here I think our current policy of considering **pure programming** questions in **any language** to be **off-topic** and punting them to https://stackoverflow.com is basically correct, but we still should take some time to make sure before voting to close that there isn't a **conceptual error** behind this, which would make the answer (and by extension, the question) **on topic**.

Comment: I want to support this move with more than one vote (not possible, unfortunately). I have at least 4 questions (LAPACK, GMSH, etc.) I managed to answer just in time before they got closed. (I would say some have been closed already after my answer was given and sometimes accepted) and all of them would fit without a doubt into the guideline proposed in this answer.

Comment: Something they have on MathOverflow is a [Meta question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/223) where everyone can post an answer to propose a closed or deleted question for reopening (arguing why it should be) -- this gives more visibility than simply casting a reopen vote and trusting the queue. Maybe after the discussion settles here, you want to open such a post and propose your questions there!

Comment: I also think that we need to revisit the policy. And reading the Area 51 site, even the definition of the community. But I have two question: how many people should agree to make the changes?, how do we invite people to the discussion?

Comment: Do you as a moderator have an option to mention all the top users in this post? (I don't think this will be abusing mod privileges) As most people do not check the Meta very often, and this is a crucial question in my mind.

Another option is to have a notification in a yellow bubble, like how SO does for important decisions.

Comment: @nicoguaro First, I don't see this as an actual change in the scope of the site, just one particular interpretation of it (and I wouldn't worry about the text on Area 51). So I don't think any moderator-level powers are called for (with the possible exception of adapting the help-center text, but a) I don't think that's far from what I wrote and b) nobody seems to read those, anyway...) In the end, people with the privileges will behave as they see fit; but they might be swayed by linking to a highly-voted meta post.

Comment: Regarding visibility: There's the [meta-tag:featured] tag a moderator can apply to a question to make it show up on main. (I think that's what Anton meant in his comment.)

Comment: @nicoguaro Mentioning all top users may be overkill (and apart from your fellow moderators and Wolfgang Bangerth, they seem no longer as active), but it might be good to involve the two other people who seem to be actively working on the Close Votes queue (Kirill and Mauro Vanzetto).

Comment: I agree with the ideas here, but one comment: except for the bullet "what is clearly answered in the documentation is off-topic", I kind of thought these are the ideas I was following anyway. I remember voting to close a lot of really lazy content-free questions, but now that you mention it I can't tell if I was being trigger-happy or if the questions would have been off-topic even taking your ideas into account. In any case, I'll try to follow other people and community standards on this.

Comment: Another thought: maybe one reason off-topic standards can ossify is that there isn't enough visible disagreement about them? What if there was an informal rule that if I press the "leave open" button on a question with some close votes already, I should seriously consider leaving a comment disagreeing with the close votes? Would that be helpful? E.g., in the questions Anton mentions answering above, he clearly thought them to be worth answering, but looking at one (that I could find) there is no discussion, not one comment.

Comment: @Kirill Just to be clear, I didn't mention your name because I thought you were *closing* a lot of questions, but because you were *handling* a lot of questions (including casting "Leave Open" votes) -- and hence your views on this are important to shape consensus. And I agree, we could and should leave more comments -- I think those are actually more useful in moderating than the actual queue buttons. (It's important to remember that these weren't built for a small site like ours but to stem the tide on StackOverflow...)

Comment: I always try to leave comments and vote for closing as the last vote. I also normally wait two days after I leave a comment.

Comment: @Kirill yeah, I kind of knew that those questions are "off-topic" according to the current interpretation of the rules, so even though I voted "leave open" I decided not to have a discussion about it. Mostly because I was able to answer the question anyway and help the OP - which is one of the goals.

I was kind of waiting for someone to start a discussion like that in Meta - or find some time to formulate those thoughts. That's why I am very thankful to Christian.

Comment: @Kirill Another thing you (or anybody else) can do is to upvote the question -- I'm much more likely to vote "Leave Open" if I see that other people think this question is useful to have around even if it might be somewhat off-topic. (Case in point: the recent MPI question https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/29671/can-i-mpi-test-for-an-ibarrier)

Comment: @MauroVanzetto, what's your take on this topic.

Comment: Hi, I see only today this post. Well I agree with the line to be more permissive, especially for the math part (here I refer in particular to numerical analysis). In my opinion this site has got a natural overlapping with the tag numerical-methods of math.stackexchange, but in my opinion this is not a problem the two areas are intrinsically linked.

Comment: For the computer science/programming part it is ok to open a little bit especially for the questions that are not well covered by computer science people. For example question about speed up code and internal functionally of some numerical library. We are lucky because now there is a border question: [this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/29716/accelerate-computation-speed-by-using-a-different-syntax) -- This ask for standard language command, but with an interest for speed up... I think we can consider ok. What do you think?

Comment: I also agree with the idea that if a question is quite upvoted also some off topic is goo to left open. It is useful also because we can have the idea about the user orientation --  @nicoguaro I tag you here only to notify the answers :-)

Comment: @MauroVanzetto, I think that the question serves well the purpose for the discussion... since it already has two close votes.

Comment: @MauroVanzetto It's especially useful since it highlights a problem I've often noticed: off-topic flags are used to close a poorly formulated question (presumably because they seem more objective). In this case, I'd say the question is in fact on topic but much too broad (or unclear) -- the answer will be completely different in different situations.

Comment: Regarding the section starting with "As long as the software is clearly targeting scientific computing", I generally agree with the point of view discussed here. As a specific example, we usually close questions along the lines of "how do I do xyz in COMSOL." Possibly many of these should be left open and we should try to grow the COMSOL expertise on CSE (I know very little about COMSOL, myself).

Comment: @BillGreene COMSOL is a good example, because it has its own Q&A-style site (https://www.comsol.com/community/) -- if we were to invite COMSOL usage questions here, this would either duplicate content or split the answers. Do we want that? Or should we require askers to try there first and only post here (with a link) after they haven't received answers there? (I'm starting to think such a "procedural" policy would be much more transparent and enforceable than a content-based one such as "has to require software *and* scientific expertise to answer".)

Comment: Yes, many of these tools do have their own Q&A sites (matlab being a prime example) but I think there are definitely reasons why users aren't getting good answers to their questions on those and CSE may be better. Regarding the question of "enforceable policy", I come back to one of your first comments that I strongly agree with: "for a site of our size, we don't have much to gain by being exclusive." So I thing we should avoid policies like requiring users to post on a code-specific site first.

Comment: @BillGreene So would you draw the line anywhere? What about "I tried to install X and got error message Y" or "How do I plot in Z"? Or are you arguing for *any* software question to be on-topic here as long as the software is related to computational science? Or is the only point of contention the existence of other Q&As. (I'm not being facetious, I'm honestly interested in your opinion, which seems to be the first one that significantly differs from the old policy. Also, "enforceable policy" was poorly phrased; better read "clear and objective consensus".)

Comment: @BillGreene I'm being picky here since I recall the discussion about FEniCs (https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353, https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368) which ended with that community leaving SciComp.SE completely and in some disappointment -- I would like to not see this experience repeated.

Comment: Good questions. I guess my opinion does differ significantly from the old (current) policy. My first reaction to your "how do I install X" question was that we should close questions like that. But, on reflecting more, I think perhaps we should be more open-minded about how do I install FEniCs or DEAL, for example. Basically, I think the attitude toward "how do I do X in Y" or "how do I install Y" should be very different for libraries or applications that are entirely (or primarily) oriented toward CSE.

Comment: I think that rejecting the FEniCs users because of "how do I do X in  FEniCs" questions was a big mistake for CSE. Beyond that, whether there are other non-SE Q&A sites for the application/library should be completely irrelevant to CSE.

Comment: @BillGreene It wasn't quite "rejecting", but I agree that we could/should have handled this differently. I guess the concern with install-type questions is that we could end up with a stream of endless variations of the same question -- we'd have to be much more proactive in turning these into authoritative FAQ-type questions. Would you mind writing up an answer based on your view so that people can vote on it?

Comment: Hi, maybe is better to open a chat :-). In these days I am trying some cfd software and I meet problem with install/compile... I start google and I found that all the relevant page are forum (cfd-online), now I suspect that the most useful format for the final user is a forum and not Q/A site (multiple post in the same thread). Oblivious we can decide question by question if an install request is on topic or no, but this gray area maybe  can generate confusion friction. So this point needs to be take with more attention. Instead include "how do I do X in Y" for computational library can be....

Comment: useful to expand the community. Here the main discriminating factor whether to keep the question open or not is the user's commitment to reading the documentation before asking the question. No work => question close in this way we can stem the tide of low quality questions. @BillGreene

Comment: @nicoguaro                                                                                                                                               (sorry Christian Clason for the extra comment)

Comment: Hi, after some months with the new policy, how are things going?

Comment: @nicoguaro (sorry Christian Clason for the extra comment, maybe better a chat)

Comment: @AntonMenshov  (sorry Christian Clason for the extra comment, maybe better a chat)

Comment: For what it's worth: I'm not in favour of leaving open "install questions" or "debug my input file questions" (unless the bug is related to numerical analysis, like using an unfit algorithm). What I do think we could try to make the site more inclusive is to accept software specific questions if we know that there is involvement (active answering of questions) by the developers of that package. If not already a member here, they could be invited by email ("Your package has generated X number of questions the past month, would you join our community to answer them?").

Answer (score 6):

I strongly support the premise of this question and have some suggestions relative
to questions about so-called "niche" libraries and applications.

Many times these niche libraries and applications can help someone
avoid a huge amount of re-inventing of the wheel. But often they are poorly-supported
by their developers. A broader forum, like CSE, gives the user a better chance
of finding someone who can help or suggest an alternative package.
But the CSE help document discourages users from asking questions about these
if another application-specific help site exists or the question is not
considered too mundane, e.g., I don't think questions on installing and running
these niche libraries/applications should automatically be off-topic.
Also, I think the existence of alternate support forums should be completely
irrelevant to CSE.

I propose the following specific changes to the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page:

The sentence "Package developers interested in using this site as a 
resource should look at this meta question." should be deleted. The
linked meta question points to a discussion mainly about why FEniCs users were
discouraged from using the CSE site. Instead we should be **encouraging** users
of FEniCs and similar computational tools to ask questions on CSE.

Perhaps a sentence like this should be added to this section:

"Questions that ask "How can I do X with software package Y?" should begin
with a brief description of the problem being solved and why you chose
package Y to solve it."

In the next section, the bullet starting with
"Questions about niche software packages and bugs"
should be deleted.

I think these changes are consistent with the statement above,
"we don't have much to gain by being exclusive 
"(and much more to gain by gaining a reputation for being welcoming".
These small changes may do some good and are unlikely to do much harm.

Comment: I up-vote the post. Personally I still have got some doubt about the black hole represented by the installation questions, because these kind of questions need, many times, of a support step by step more suitable for a forum. However, if this will became a problem, in future we can restrict the policy in easy way. Good the idea to be more permissive with questions "How can I do X with software package Y?", it can help to expand community. (this comment is a resume of my previous comments writed before this question appears, in this way it is more well-ordered)

Answer (score 3):

I think, currently, [On-Topic](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page describes our views well. We reserve the right to close the questions that are very-very deeply specific for a specialized scientific software package OR very "debug my code" questions.

The aforementioned types of questions rarely serve the crowd and are generally not "fun" to answer.

I try to follow this logic when voting to Close/Leave Open questions; however, I, personally, have to make more comments under questions with my particular motivation.

Answer (score 2):

I would start a community post for related questions and discussions.

- [Are software-recommendation questions on topic here?](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/501/9667)