# Are software-recommendation questions on topic here?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

The question [Is there an alternative to SIMION?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/440879/is-there-an-alternative-to-simion) was posted recently on the physics site. It sounds like something that may be better suited for this community, but I'm not sure to what extent software-recommendation questions (or other threads that can be argued to fall under the broader 'shopping' umbrella as defined in the early days of SO) are welcome or encouraged here; I looked on this meta but I couldn't find anything explicit, either because there isn't an existing thread with the right keywords or because I just mucked up the search.

Are questions like that one on-topic here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Judging by some of the top-voted questions on this site, it seems that the community is open to software recommendation questions.  I don’t recall any particular instances where such a question was not welcome, as long as:

1. It is not subject to closure under our standard criteria (e.g. too broad, unclear, etc...).
2. It involves a scientific field that heavily relies on computation and therefore has well established tools of the trade.
3. It is not a duplicate of a previous software recommendation request.

There is some overlap between such inquiries on this site and the software recommendation SE site  (maybe even the Engineering SE too), but i think if you’re looking specifically for scientific modeling and simulation software, this site would probably be open to it.